Fancyhdr + biblatex : page after \printbibliography keep the bibliography header
as the MWE shows, i would like to add some text (basicly an abstract) after the bibliography. I would like the page to be without any header, but here the header of the bibliography section is still active if the text is longer than one page, ever with the \thispagestyle{empty} command.
I found here that adding \fancyhead{} could help but as you can see if you uncomment, it only removes the header so the line is still here.
I also found here that \markboth may help, but it seems to only makes it possible to change the text in the header.
Do you have any idea on how should i do to solve this ?
Thanks,
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage} 
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
Main text with citation \cite{test} here.

\newpage
\printbibliography


\newpage
%\fancyhead{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum %Another long text here
\end{document}

% The "biblio.bib" file :

%@article{test,
%   title = {test},
%   doi = {test},
%   journaltitle = {test},
%   author = {test,test},
%   date = {test},
%}


Use \pagestyle{empty} to switch off the header for all following pages.

Ok... that simple, thx !

Welcome to TeX.SE!
